# Some Important Filters for Stack Careers Jobs' Listing

Tags: feature-request, jobs, filtering

When we visit http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?f=t Right now stackcareers display list of careers with respect to our search query. But it will be very beneficial if we could have useful filters here.

Likewise we have in other stack sites. If we talk about stackoverflow we have tabs for New/Hot/Featured questions. In the same way we can have tabs in searched jobs like FullTime/PartTime/WORK REMOTELY/OFFERS RELOCATION.